# Roblox parental control does not work

Tags: roblox

my 8-year old daughter plays Roblox and the parental controls I had set up in Roblox worked fine. Then my daughter said she was able to access lots of new games. She is not tech savvy enough to be able to get around controls. I have contacted Roblox support but they weren’t very helpful and said that it was a restricted account due to her age. I have gone over the parental controls several times, deleted and reinstalled the app but she can still play all games. Can anyone help please? Thanks so much.

Comment: Do you mean access more games _within_ roblox or on the device?

Comment: Yes she can now access all games within Roblox.

Comment: I have seen this too. They changed their parental controls but told no parents. They now have age ratings rather then the previous special curated games for under ages. This gives all kids access to any game that has selected all ages even when it obviously isn't.